# EFCore/C# - Collection Modified -> Operation may not execute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following loop. As soon as the first iteration succeeds, I get the following error:
[image]

In no place inside the `for` loop I am changing either `weeklyReportsList` or `weeklyReport1.DailyReports`, so I don't understand where the error is coming from, I can't seem to find the location where the Collection might be modified

**Code**

```
foreach (var weeklyReport1 in weeklyReportsList)
            {
                foreach(var dailyReport in weeklyReport1.DailyReports)
                {
                    _context.Attach(dailyReport);

                    User user = GetDataUser(Convert.ToInt32(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value));

                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        _toastNotification.AddErrorToastMessage("Utilizador não encontrado.");
                        OnGet();
                        return Page();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dailyReport.UserCreator = user;
                    }

                    /*dailyReport.States = GetDataStates(state);
                    _context.Entry(dailyReport).Reference(dr => dr.States).IsModified = true;*/

                    dailyReport.EstimatedDate = nextDate;
                    _context.Entry(dailyReport).Property(dr => dr.EstimatedDate).IsModified = true;

                    dailyReport.WeeklyReportId = nextWeeklyReport.Id;
                    dailyReport.WeekDay = GetWeekDayName((DateTime)dailyReport.EstimatedDate);

                    try
                    {
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateException e)
                    {
                        _toastNotification.AddErrorToastMessage("Falha ao editar Registo");
                        Console.Write(e);
                        return RedirectToPage("Index");
                    }

                    _context.Entry(dailyReport).State = EntityState.Detached;
                    await CreateLog(dailyReport.Id);
                }
            }

public async Task<IActionResult> CreateLog(int id)
        {
            DailyReport editedDailyReport = GetDailyReport(id);
            User user = GetDataUser(Convert.ToInt32(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value));
            LogReports logReports = new LogReports(editedDailyReport, "Edição Registo Atrasado", user.Id);
            _context.LogReportsReception.Add(logReports);

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException e)
            {
                Console.Write(e);
                _toastNotification.AddWarningToastMessage("Log Registo não criado");
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**PS:** All other functions (`Get...()`) are data retrieval related only. No attributions whatsoever there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection that you iterate with foreach may not be modified during iteration.
So, you cannot modify the elements in this way.
You can however loop through a copy of the collection. For instance Collection.ToList() at the loop instantiation. This will let you modify your actual collection in the loop while not altering the "Copy" of the Collection.
You can verify this by changing:

```
foreach(var dailyReport in weeklyReport1.DailyReports)
```

To

```
foreach(var dailyReport in weeklyReport1.DailyReports.ToList())
```

Comment: This worked as expected. Still, I don't know how was I trying to change the collection, because in no place was I altering `weeklyReport1` or `weeklyReport1.DailyReports`. It's a variable I define before the foreach loop and I never call it again...